# Find match from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm working on a Rails application where I have users that can add each other as friends.
Now I'm trying to display certain information for when a user is already a friend of another user. I have done this in the following fashion:

```
- @users.each do |user|


- exists = false
  - current_user.friends.each do |friend|
   - if friend == user
    - exists = true

  - if !exists
   = button_to 'Add Friend', friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post
  - else
   Already a friend
```

I think this solution isn't nice. Do you know how I can do this in a clean and more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Enumerable#any? method to do that

```
- @users.each do |user|
  - if current_user.friends.any?{ |friend| friend == user }
   Already a friend
  - else
   = button_to 'Add Friend', friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post
```

Like explain in Comment, the Enumerable#include? works too in this case

```
- @users.each do |user|
  - if current_user.friends.include?(user)
   Already a friend
  - else
   = button_to 'Add Friend', friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. One minor comment; the if/else contents should be switched.

Comment: Even simpler: `current_user.friends.include? user`